# Is it possible to load MainWindow programmatically

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loading a view controller & view hierarchy programmatically in Cocoa Touch without xib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809898/loading-a-view-controller-view-hierarchy-programmatically-in-cocoa-touch-witho)

I know it can load via set MainWindow in Target Summary.
It show as

[image]

Is it possible to load MainWindow programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.. here is how you will create it pragmatically,

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```